# expected identifier or '(' in xcode 4.6.1

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am trying to get an add button to add rows to a table, which can then be edited.
I am getting the expected identifier or '(' for lines 10, 17, and 30.  Here is the code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UILabel *lblName = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    [lblName setText:[intervalArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];
    return cell;
}

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                   reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}


if ([indexPath section]) == 0 {
    UITextField *workoutTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 10, 185, 30)];
    workoutTextField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    workoutTextField.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    if ([indexPath row] == 0) {
        workoutTextField.placeholder = @"...";
        workoutTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress;
        workoutTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyNext;

 }}

// Configure the cell...

return cell;
```

I have tried your suggestions and they got rid of all of the errors, but I am still not able to add rows to my table with the button.  Any suggestions on how to go about adding rows to the table would be greatly appreciated, this is my first iOS app and I am fairly new to programming in general.  Thanks for all of the help!
I am using OS X 10.8.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you misplaced a parenthesis here:

```
if ([indexPath section]) == 0 {
```

You mean:

```
if ([indexPath section] == 0) {
```

The square brackets here are enclosing a *method call* or *message send* to `indexPath`; the parentheses enclose the *condition* or *comparison* you're making, which is to check if the result of calling `[indexPath section]` is equal to zero.

**EDIT:** You may also have a closing curly brace too soon - the `}` on line 7 closes your entire implementation of the method `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. You may want to move that all the way down to below your `return cell;` statement.

Comment: Yes... you find the answer :) +1

Answer (score 1):

To what method do the conditionals at lines 10 and 17 and the `return` statement at line 30 belong?  They appear to be stuck in your implementation file, which is confusing the compiler.

Simply moving the curly brace that ends `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` will fix the errors, but since you are returning a value on line 7 (ending execution of the method), the rest of the code won't do anything.